# Azure DevOps build pipeline - Conditionally exclude file from trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

#### Current state

Multiple product teams share a `build.yml` file that allows each team to create an Azure DevOps build pipeline that generates and publishes each product's documentation. Therefore, `build.yml` can't be customized. However, each team can use a `variables.yml` file to enact conditions that customize `build.yml` to their needs. To illustrate, here are select portions of `build.yml` and `variables.yml` that allow teams to determine if they want `stylesPath.sh` to run in the build.

##### build.yml

```
variables:
- template: variables.yml

trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main

steps:
- task: Bash@3
  condition: eq(variables['RaiseRelativeStylePaths'], 'true')
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)$(DocsRootDirectory)/stylesPath.sh'
```

##### variables.yml

```
variables:
- name: RaiseRelativeStylePaths
  value: true
```

#### Desired state

I would like to use this approach to conditionally exclude `Nuget.Config` from the build because not all teams may want that to happen. Something like (I know the syntax is incorrect - I'm just trying to illustrate):

##### build.yml

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    condition: eq(variables['ExcludeNugetConfig'], 'true')
    exclude:
      - Nuget.Config
```

##### variables.yml

```
- name: ExcludeNugetConfig
  value: true
```

Thank you for any help on this or guidance on better approaches.

Comment: You don't want changes to `Nuget.Config` to trigger a build? Or you don't `Nuget.Config` included in the source code when a build is run? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I don't want `Nuget.Config` included in the source code when the build begins. The build runs a documentation generator that fails if `Nuget.Config` exists.

Comment: `paths` is part of defining a trigger. Excluding `Nuget.Config` in `paths` in `trigger` means that a change to `Nuget.Config` will not trigger the start of a build. The file, however, will still in included in the source code used for the build. Modifying the `trigger` is not going to help for your use case.

Comment: Is this a git repo or a TFVC repo? With a TFVC repo when the 'get' of the source is performed, it can be configured with workspace mappings to only retrieve parts of the repo. This feature doesn't exist for git.

Comment: @Jonathan Dodds It is a Git repo. Thanks for the explanation on why this can't be done.